# Index maintenance on pg_catalog tables in AWS RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, vacuum, aws-aurora

I have had some bad historical usage on my Aurora PostgreSQL instance. Namely, connections that create a lot of temporary objects and some very long running transactions (which limits autovacuum).

Now I have some very, very bloat pg_catalog indices.

For example: pg_attribute has only 34k records but *pg_attribute_relid_attnam_index and pg_attribute_relid_attnum_index are 630MB and 450MB!*

In total I have gigabytes of  (bloated) system indices on system tables. However, I cannot REINDEX or VACUUM FULL these tables due to permissions.

Is this situation correctable in any way? Or is my RDS managed database permanently hosed and I need to migrate to a new one.

Answer (score 0):

`REINDEX INDEX` didn't work because PostgreSQL checks the index owner (which is `rdsadmin`).

However, `REINDEX SYSTEM` and `REINDEX DATABASE` only check the database owner (which is myself).

So

```sql
REINDEX SYSTEM <database>
```

fixes the issue.